# Infinispan alternative for Golang (embedded solution)

Tags: go, caching, infinispan

I'm trying to create a fully horizontal scalable API service in Go where I need to update the internal cache of all running instances when the state changes to an aggregate in one of them. I initially got inspired of how Keycloak does the same without introducing an external message broker (another fail-point), but rather uses multicast directly through the use of the Infinispan library.

Do such distributed in-memory cache solution already exists for Go?

Regards, Karl.

Comment: something like https://github.com/golang/groupcache?

Comment: github.com/golang/groupcache should be a good solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It seems 'memcached' is more suitable for my usecase.</strike>

https://github.com/iwanbk/bcache - distributed in-memory cache for Go. This eliminates the need for another service running, thus a failure-point less to worry about.